# Proof about n variables polynomial that identically vanish

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, induction

I worked out a proof that if $p(x_1,...,x_n)=0$ for every $\vec a\in\mathbb{F}^{n}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is an infinite field, then $P$ is the zero polynomial.
The proof is by induction. Base case is obvious. I assume that for every polynomial with $n-1$ variables the claim holds.

Now let's assume we have a polynomial $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ that vanishes for every $\vec a$. I fix $x_n$ and look at $p$ as a polynomial in $n-1$ variables (call it $g$), where the coefficients are in $\mathbb{F}[x_n]$. By induction assumption, since $g$ vanishes for every $\vec a$ ($\vec a\in\mathbb{F}^{n-1}$) then all the coefficients are 0.

Now I look at $p$ as a single variable polynomial (name it $q$) with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$. Since it vanishes for every $a\in\mathbb{F}$ we know that all the coefficients are zero.

So we get that all the coefficients of $p$ are zero as we wanted.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: If $p$ is non-zero, you need to find $a_n\in \Bbb{F}$ such that  $p(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},a_n)$ is non-zero

Comment: @reuns How do I find such $a_n$? And what did I do wrong in my proof?

Comment: The coefficient of $x_n^r \prod_{j<n} x_j^{e_j}$ is non-zero, then the coefficient of $\prod_{j<n} x_j^{e_j}$ in $p(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},a_n)$ is a polynomial in $a_n$, of degree $d$, trying $d+1$ values of $a_n$ gives one non-zero polynomial $p(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},a_n)$